# Replace implementation of an AuthPlugin with new AuthManager

Tags: php, authentication, mediawiki

My Problem, the guides and docu is kind of complicated and confusing.
It is only set "implement a [ClassName]", but nowhere is shown an example.

My given Code (old code that a have to rewrite) is following:

```
class MyAuthPlugin extends AuthPlugin {

  protected $isAuthenticated = false;
           
  function modifyUITemplate( &$template ) {
      $template->set( 'usedomain', false );
      $template->set( 'useemail',  false ); 
      $template->set( 'canreset',  false );
      $template->set( 'create',    false );
  }


  function autoCreate() {
      return true;
  }

  function userExists( $username ) {  
      return true;  //already handled in ohter function
  }

  function strict() {   
      return true;  
  }

  /* Being called twice:
   * Login->attemptAutoCreate() (SpecialUserLogin.php) (only for new)
   * User->checkPassword() (User.php) external PW-authentication.  
   */   
  function authenticate( $username, $password ) {
      global $BBredirect, $BBconnection, $wgRequest;

      if($this->isAuthenticated) return true;
    
      $BBConnection['Parameters']  = 'cmd=authenticate&sessionId='.$wgRequest->getVal('sessionId');
    
      $myRequest = new SimpleHttpRequest($BBConnection);
      $responseGET = $myRequest->doRequest(SimpleHttpRequest::HTTP_GET);
      echo ($responseGET[Content]);
    
      $auth = simplexml_load_string($responseGET[Content]);

      if($auth->response->authentication ==  'false') {
          return false;
      }
        
      if($auth->response->authentication == 'ok') {
          $this->isAuthenticated = true;
      }
      return $this->isAuthenticated;
  }

  function isAuthenticated() {
      return $this->isAuthenticated;
  }

}
```

How can I transform this code into the new AuthManager style?
This [guide](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:SessionManager_and_AuthManager/Updating_tips#The_AuthPlugin_and_AuthPluginUser_classes) suggest so many different classes..

- userExists() → PrimaryAuthenticationProvider::testUserExists()
- authenticate() → PrimaryAuthenticationProvider::beginPrimaryAuthentication + PasswordAuthenticationRequest (how do i pass the password to the process?)
- modifyUITemplate() → AuthenticationRequests from AuthenticationProvider (How?) + AuthChangeFormFields hook.
- autoCreate() has no direct replacement. (AuthenticationResponse-> from where? Just want to force autocreation)
- strict() → Don't return ABSTAIN  (What should i do instead? Don't want to have local authentication)
- How do I instantiate my class? with `$wgAuth = new MyAuthPLugin()`
  is deprecated says the docu.

Or is there a simply way to auto-login when username, password(hash), sessionID and secretkey is given int the html-Request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

- create an [AbstractPrimaryAuthenticationProvider](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classMediaWiki_1_1Auth_1_1AbstractPrimaryAuthenticationProvider.html) subclass
- implement `getAuthenticationRequests`; you probably want to return a new `PasswordAuthenticationRequest` object on `ACTION_LOGIN` and nothing otherwise (since you don't want to support creating BB users / changing their passwords via the wiki).
- implement `beginPrimaryAuthentication`; it will be roughly the same as the old `authenticate` except you get the credentials as an array of `AuthenticationRequest` objects and use `AuthenticationRequest::getRequestByClass( $reqs, PasswordAuthenticationRequest::class )` to get the right one, then return `AuthenticationResponse::newXXX` to signal the outcome (`newPass` or `newFail` - no abstaining since you don't want to support falling back to another authentication method). Autocreation is automatic if the user does not exist locally.
- implement `testUserExists`. This should look up the user in the BB database. (Just returning true or false all the time would probably work as well - this is mostly so that a provider can reserve names and prevent other providers from taking it.)
- implement `beginPrimaryAccountCreation` and `accountCreationType`. Since you probably don't want to support BB account creation via the wiki, just return `AuthenticationResponse::newFail` and `TYPE_NONE`, respectively.
- implement `providerAllowsAuthenticationDataChange` and `providerChangeAuthenticationData`. The first should return an error when it gets a password authentication request and ignore it otherwise. The second should be empty.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me to get a start. How do i have to instantiate this class? is there a replacement for `$wgAuth = new MyClass();` ?

Comment: You don't, you just tell AuthManager how to instantiate it, via [`Manual:$wgAuthManagerAutoConfig`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAuthManagerAutoConfig).